# batch script to ping specified ip addresses?

Tags: windows, batch-file, ping

I want to write a batch script under Windows to ping a specified range of IP addresses. Like I want to ping 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.10 and want to check if their response is coming or not under Windows batch script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /L %%i in (1,1,10) do (
@echo testing 192.168.0.%%i 
ping 192.168.1.%%i > nul
if ERRORLEVEL 1 @echo error ping %%i )
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `for` loop would look like this:

```
for /l %i in (1,1,10) do ping 192.168.0.%i
```

So the script would be something like:

```
for /l %i in (1,1,10) do (
    ping 192.168.0.%i
    if %errorlevel% neq 0 echo error
)
```

Comment: Your "error" line will never print. Use `if errorlevel 1` instead. In any case, you don't need it since the output of `ping` is enough to gauge success or not.

Comment: No, tried that.  ping returns a negative integer if the host could not be found.